# Entering data into Backend Less table

Tags: javascript, backendless

I started using Backend Less to support a project I'm making. But I'm unable to figure out how to enter data. Here's my code:

```
var APP_ID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
var API_KEY = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';

Backendless.serverURL = 'https://api.backendless.com';
Backendless.initApp(APP_ID, API_KEY);

Backendless.Data.of( "User" ).save( { username:"user2", password:"Password2" } )
.then( function( obj ) {
    console.log( "object saved. objectId " + obj.objectId )
} )
.catch( function( error ) {
    console.log( "got error - " + error )
})
```

I have created a table named "User" with the columns, username and password. It still doesn't enter any values. Am I missing something?

Comment: First, I would not recommend mentioning your personal API key in a public post. Moreover it would help to describe the result of the API call in more detail - error message or any information from the service.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "how to enter data" ?

Just checked your data table, the data you're storing is there:
[image: data table snapshot]